# What is the type parameter in the bytestring builder internals for?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

The core datatypes of `Data.ByteString.Builder` are

```
newtype Builder = Builder (forall r. BuildStep r -> BuildStep r)

type BuildStep a = BufferRange -> IO (BuildSignal a)

data BuildSignal a =
    Done {-# UNPACK #-} !(Ptr Word8) a
  | BufferFull
      {-# UNPACK #-} !Int 
      {-# UNPACK #-} !(Ptr Word8)
                     (BuildStep a)
  | InsertChunk
      {-# UNPACK #-} !(Ptr Word8)
                     S.ByteString
                     (BuildStep a)
```

What purpose does the type parameter (`r` or `a`) serve?

Comment: I suspect it's similar to the phantom parameter in `ST` – it prevents you from using pointers in a context where the data doesn't exist.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Doesn't look like phantom type parameter since there's a field with type `a` in `Done` constructor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Can you expand on that functionality with `ST` or do you maybe have a reference?

Comment: @sjakobi the [`ST` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Lazy-Safe.html#t:ST) has an extra `s` parameter that's not actually used for anything. The type system ensures this parameter is “synchronised” along any given mutable computation. For actually getting any result out of such a computation, you need to use `runST`, whose Rank-2 type prevents you from fixing the `s` to anything particular. So if you smuggle out a reference to e.g. a mutable array out of such a computation, there is you can do with it elsewhere, because the `s` type doesn't match.

Answer (score 5):

It is not needed. As proof, I have [created a fork](https://github.com/dmwit/bytestring/tree/0c5bec644c098c7a9cb445279c5039d591a54638) which does not change any of the public APIs -- only the API of modules named `Internal` -- but removes this type argument.

Comment: Do you happen to know what `bytestring`'s compat policy is like for `Internal` modules? I know that eg `attoparsec` actually does rummage around in `bytestring`'s internals ([example](https://github.com/bos/attoparsec/blob/master/Data/Attoparsec/ByteString/Buffer.hs#L57)), so, like it or not, changing internal APIs might break downstream dependencies. I imagine the `bytestring` maintainers might be willing to accept such a PR with a major rev bump...

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, @daniel-wagner! I've noticed that Simon Meier's [original design](http://lambda-view.blogspot.de/2010/11/on-design-of-efficient-builder-monoid.html) doesn't have the type arguments, but I'm still wondering why they were added.

Comment: @sjakobi I suspect it was put there as a "Just In Case": just in case somebody wanted to compute some interesting, potentially structured value *about* the `ByteString` as they were building it. Then it turned out not to be the case that people wanted to do that -- at least, not in the code we have today in the library. Whether there's somebody out there relying on that capability is a question we may never be able to reasonably answer in the negative.

Comment: @Shersh Perhaps. Somebody interested in turning it into a PR would probably want to be more careful about ripping out only what wasn't possible any more without the extra type parameter. I went for the changes that were easiest to throw together and verify type-checked rather than the minimal change -- and I'm not super interested in doing the work that's likely needed to take the patch from "proof of concept" to "acceptable to the bytestring maintainers". Of course, if you care about this, you're welcome to do that yourself.

Comment: Well, as I already commented, the purpose of this parameter might actually just be to _prevent_ some (incorrect) code from compiling, not to do anything for correct code.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It is insufficiently polymorphic to serve that role. (I verified this mentally as I was refactoring.)

Comment: @Shersh: I have created https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/154 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Simon Meier, the author of this `Builder` design, [has responded](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/154#issuecomment-466828601) to my question on the `bytestring` issue tracker:

> The type parameter was there to support the `Put` monad (a `Writer` spezialized to fill a buffer during the computation of its value).

[`Put`](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/blob/715094d380e4d76e734f55c71e739a9d38901ee8/Data/ByteString/Builder/Internal.hs#L456) is defined as

```
newtype Put a = Put { unPut :: forall r. (a -> BuildStep r) -> BuildStep r }
```

and exported from `Data.ByteString.Builder.Internal` which is hidden in the current `bytestring` release.